# Can't get jquery If-Else to function properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

It might be that I've been staring at this for too long, and the function I've written isn't really that complicated, but for whatever reason, I cannot get this to function properly.  The h1 tag changes as it should, but my if-else doesn't seem to be functioning based on the "page_layout" variable.  My code is below... any ideas?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
     function() {
         //Set text for H1 tags here
         var title = "Test title";

         //Set main-image layout here (1,2,3,4)
         var page_layout = "1";

         //If page_layout = 4, then set connected-image for top
         var connected_image = "images/connected-image.jpg";

         //Image for main-image area
         var main_image = "images/main-image.jpg";

         //Set main-image text here
         var main_image_text = "See how this works.";

         //Set main-image-text-url location
         var main_image_text_url = "http://www.example.com";

         //Do not touch this code
        $('h1').html(title);

        if (page_layout == "1"){
            $.('#main-image').css('background-image', main_image);
            $.('#main-image').css('background-position', 'top right');
            $.('#main-image').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
            $.('#main-image').addClass('padding-21');
            $.('#main-image').html(main_image_text);
            $.('#main-image').append('<br><a href="' + main_image_text_url + '">tell me more</a>');
        }else if (page_layout == "2"){
            $.('#middle').css('font-size','15px');
            $.('#main-image').addClass('padding-21');
            $.('#main-image').html(main_image_text);
            $.('#main-image').append('<br><a href="' + main_image_text_url + '">tell me more</a>');
        }else if (page_layout == "3"){
            $.('#main-image').css('background-image', main_image);
            $.('#main-image').css('background-position', 'top left');
            $.('#main-image').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
            $.('#main-image').addClass('padding-491');
            $.('#main-image').html(main_image_text);
            $.('#main-image').append('<br><a href="' + main_image_text_url + '">tell me more</a>');
        }else if (page_layout == "4"){
            $.('connected-image').css('background-image', connected_image );
            $.('connected-image').css('background-position', 'top right');
            $.('connected-image').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
        }else{
            //Nothing
        }
     }
    )
</script>
```

Comment: What is your code doing and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: The `if` statement looks fine to me ... what is the code **not** doing that you expect it to do ? have you included all of the code ? because to me it suggests that `page_layout` has its value dynamically changed ...

Comment: jQuery doesn't support IF-Else. That's JavaScript.

Comment: I'm assuming there's more code that you haven't shared.

Comment: Based on the page_layout variable, certain CSS properties need to be applied to various DIVs.  Have I structured this incorrectly within the main $(document).ready function?

Comment: page_layout is changed in this line: 

//Set main-image layout here (1,2,3,4)
         var page_layout = "1";

Comment: How is `page_layout` changed? As far as I can see in your code, it's only ever `1`. Also, using a `switch` statement for this construct would be better practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you should be seeing some syntax errors in the javascript console. You need to change your selectors from `$.('selector')` to `$('selector')` (remove the `.` after `$`).

Also, `$('connected-image')` should probably be using a class selector `$('.connected-image')`.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that?  This works fine.  Sorry to bug you all.

Answer (score 2):

There may be other issues as its not really clear what behavior you're seeing, but you shouldn't need periods in between the $ and open parens.

ie

```
$('connected-image').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
```

not

```
$.('connected-image').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
```

Answer (score 0):

Within each if-else block, add:

```
console.log("This is case 1");

// ... do this inside each if-else {...}

console.log("This is case 4");
```

Then reload the page with firebug console open, and check if the blocks are executing. If they are, then you know your if-else conditions are working fine, and it must be a problem with the statements inside the if-else blocks.